# Wavelength of reflected light vs transmitted light

Tags: visible-light, reflection, wavelength

In the basic setup of the experiment below, the transmitted light is used to infer the absorbed wavelengths. The explanation of the experiment states that a high transmittance reading for a specific wavelength means that wavelenght is not absorbed.Does this mean that the wavelength of the transmitted light and the reflected right are equal?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to ask about reflected light? It has nothing to do with the experiment shown in your question.

Comment: @nasu could you please explain why?

Comment: Well,  I don't see the relevance.  If you do,  what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you asking about reflected light levels?  Are you worried that the flask and/or the solution have spectrally-varying reflectances?   If so, then the standard way to deal with that is to run a reference calibration with the flask and whatever solution you intend to  use, but none of the test material itself.  Treat the transmitted power curve as a normalizer for the data you collect thru the test specimen.

Answer (score 0):

Some assumptions will have to be made here as the question and image is not very detailed.

I am guessing that you're talking about the reflected light from the slit? I.e that that does not get transmitted? This light should be either absorbed or diffusely reflected. As you can see the prism spatially separates the different wavelengths due to the refraction. By moving the slit the transmitted wavelength can then be chosen.

Comment: Lord vader.. if you move the prism without moving the slit the same can be said and what assumptions MUST be made exactly?

Comment: @jay I meant assumptions about what he is actually talking about, which reflections etc.

Answer (score 0):

There exists some time where the signal is transient and subject to `interference` from other such waves along its length about its frequency.

If you articulate what intrinsic property you are after I will try to dig it up / improve my answer.

Comment: I don't think either of your claims are correct in this situation.  We're not dealing with coherent sources, for one thing.